# Why MongoDb return a document although document does not exists

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, collections

We are using MongoDb in our game. For new installers the query works fine but when active users update the game. Although their user id not exists in the collection mongoldb return not 0. This function return false. I cannot figure it out the reason. Any ideas?

```
MongoUrl url = new MongoUrl("mongodb://...");
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(url);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var db = server.GetDatabase("databaseName");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Collection>("collectionName"); 
        var q = Query.EQ("UserId", SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier);

        return collection.Find(q).Count() == 0;
```

Comment: Have you checked the actual result of the query using debugger to see what you are getting?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. But our users say that they cannot connect to the database.

Comment: Did you test for null?  null is not zero, it is usually -1.

Comment: Before this I check for null it also return false. collection.find(q) == null return false

Comment: @ÇağatayKaya You mention users cannot connect to db that seems like a completely different issue.,

Comment: Sorry they can connect the database but this function return false so they cannot insert their data to the collection. They can see other users data from database

Comment: Updating users encounter with this problem. How it is related to the update I cannot understand.